# aggregate array base on array parameters

Tags: php

I have an array of arrays, each array hold three parameters, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [title] => 'games'
        [transaction_id] => 102
        [order_id]=> a
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [title] => 'media'
        [transaction_id] => 95
        [order_id]=> b
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [title] => 'tv'
        [transaction_id] => 102
        [order_id]=> a
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [title] => 'jane'
        [transaction_id] => 42
        [order_id]=> a
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [title] => 'ads'
        [transaction_id] => 95
        [order_id]=> b
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [title] => 'movie'
        [transaction_id] => 95
        [order_id]=> c
    )
)
```

I want to organise the array so that each array with the same `transaction_id` value and `order_id` will be under a new array in the original `array(Multidimensional)`, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => games
        [1] => tv
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => jane
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => ads
        [1] => media
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => movie
    )
)
```

What is a good way to do that?

I have tried this:

```
foreach ($conv_data as $obj) {
    if (empty($result[$obj[1]])) {
        $result[$obj[1]] = array($obj);
    } else {
        $result[$obj[1]][] = $obj;
    }
}
```

But this only aggregate on one parameter.

Comment: different order_id (c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transaction id and order id as result array key to "merge" duplication:

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/e3ERO)

```
$source=/* source array */;
function merge(array $source)
{
    $result=array();
    foreach($source as $node)
    {
        $key=$node["transaction_id"]."_".$node["order_id"];
        if(!empty($result[$key])) $result[$key][]=$node["title"];
        else $result[$key]=array($node["title"]);
    }
    return array_values($result);
}
print_r(merge($source));
```

Final result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => games
            [1] => tv
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => media
            [1] => ads
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => jane
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => movie
        )

)
```

You can [`uksort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to your desire order (if you care about it) before return.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($arrays as $k=>$v){
    $newarray['transaction_id'] = $v['transaction_id'];
    $newarray['order_id'] = $v['order_id'];
    $newmulti[] = $newarray;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newmulti);
```

> I hope it helps you